# Cannot access Identity Pool with token return from User pool in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to access Identity pool with token return from User pool after user login successful, but now I get: `These credentials are not valid for accessing this resource`. I already set UserpoolId and ClientId in Authenticate provider of Identity pool.
Here is my code

```
    AWS.config.region = 'us-xxx-xx';
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'us-xxxxxx',
        Logins: {
            'cognito-idp.us-xxx-xx.amazonaws.com/us-xxx-xxx': 'token-return-from-user-pool'
        },
    });
    const cognito = new CognitoIdentity;
    const openIdToken = await cognito.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity({
        IdentityPoolId: 'us-xxxxxx',
        Logins: {
            'cognito-idp.us-xxx-xx.amazonaws.com/us-xxx-xxx': 'token-return-from-user-pool'
        },
        TokenDuration: 3600,
    }).promise();
```

I get this error: `These credentials are not valid for accessing this resource`

Where is my wrong? Please help me

Comment: If you comment out the `getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity()` call, do you still get the same error? I'm trying to understand if the `CognitoIdentityCredentials()` call is throwing the error, because that part should work with the token returned from the User Pool. So by than stage you should have the temporary AWS credentials that you need to access AWS resources. The `getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentities()` method is for when you are using Developer Authenticated Identities, rather than identities that have been authenticated by an ID provider such as Cognito User Pool, or Facebook etc.

Comment: @lemming yes, dont need call method `getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentities` to get openIdToken because I already have token return from Cognito userpool, just call `getCredentialsForIdentity` to exchange session token